# Android app release with google signature

Tags: android, google-play-console, signed-apk

I have to add a quick fix in our app and release that app. But releasing the app could take few days.
User has already installed the app from Internal Testing Track. So if I share the apk to users, if user installs without uninstalling the existing app, will it be overwritten ? or is there any other way to create a google signed apk ?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that something you could easily have tried by yourself?

Comment: No, they don't overwrite the apk. In play store they just show you have already installed app.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thank you for the response, yes I am trying the same, wanted some expert advice and also to know if any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have access to the app signing key. If you let Google generate it, then no you can't since the signatures won't match. If you supplied Google with the key when you created the app, then yes you can since you'll be able to sign the APK with the same key and the signatures will match.